# Caching: myscript-1125.js vs myscript.js?1125

Tags: javascript, css, http, caching

Does it make any difference where you put script version? Query param or path. Pro, cons?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference!

You will want to make it part of the filename or some browsers will ***not*** cache it.

From: http://thinkvitamin.com/code/serving-javascript-fast/

> According the letter of the HTTP caching specification, user agents should never cache URLs
>   with query strings. While Internet Explorer and Firefox ignore this, Opera and Safari don’t
>   – to make sure all user agents can cache your resources, we need to keep query strings out
>   of their URLs

From: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

> Jacob Hoffman-Andrews, mentioned that Squid, a popular proxy, doesn’t cache resources with a querystring.
>   This hurts performance when multiple users behind a proxy cache request the same file
>   – rather than using the cached version everybody would have to send a request to the origin server.

(note this default behavior in Squid has [since changed](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent))

Finally, there is a great little service that will let you "ping" a page on the Internet and verify the "cacheability" of the file (and the resources it uses)

[Cacheability](http://www.ircache.net/cgi-bin/cacheability.py) - Check [www.stackoverflow.com's Cacheability](http://www.ircache.net/cgi-bin/cacheability.py?query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%2F&descend=on)

You'll notice that the CSS and JS files that StackOverflow serves up are versioned in the query string and as a result the service reports:

> This object will be fresh for 1 week.
>   It can be validated with Last-Modified.
>   Because it contains a query ('?') in the URL, many caches will not keep this object.

Comment: That document is very misleading - what the author failed to mention is (from rfc 2616) is "...unless the server provides an explicit expiration time". And you really should be specifying the js files are cacheable by default.

Comment: @symcbean - agreed there should be a cache header set too.  This was just 1 article discussing the issue but from all the in-depth articles I've read, the filename must be changed to achieve the desired caching behavior across all browsers.